# Idiom for using Jasmine with bare functions and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, function, testing, mocking, jasmine

What approach can I take to mock bare functions when working with Jasmine and RequireJS?

As far as I can tell, I cannot conveniently use `spyOn`, because that needs  the object the function is a method on. Although I *can* get this object (the RequireJS `context.defined` object), the assignment to `bareFunction` in `foo.js` has already occurred by the time the test is run, making changes to that function impossible at test-time (IIUC).

**bare-function.js**

```
define(function() {
  return function bareFunction() {
    return 'a';
  };
});
```

**foo.js**

```
define(function(require){
  var bareFunction = require('bare-function');

  return {
    doSomething: function() {
      var v = bareFunction();
      return v.toUpperCase();
    }
  };
}
```

**foo-unit-test.js**

```
define(function(require) {
  var bareFunction = require('bare-function');
  var target = require('foo');

  describe('foo', function(){

    describe('doSomething', function(){

      it('should uppercase the result of the bare-function', function() {
        //arrange
        var bareFunctionResult = 'test value';
        bareFunction.mockWith(function() { return bareFunctionResult; }); // Pseudocode.

        //act
        var result = target.doSomething();

        //assert
        expect(result).toBe(bareFunctionResult.toUpperCase());  
      });

    });

  });

});
```

The best I can come up with is attach a `__stub` method to the bare function and have the function short-circuit if this is set. e.g.

**bare-function.js**

```
define(function() {

  var stub;

  function bareFunction() {
    if(stub) {
      return stub();
    }

    return 'a';
  };

  bareFunction.__stub = function(v) {
    stub = v;
  };

  bareFunction.__unstub = function() {
    stub = null;
  };

  return bareFunction;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I modified my `foo.js` so that `doSomething` accepted an optional shadow function for `bareFunction`, enabling trivial stubbing/mocking.

**foo.js**

```
define(function(require){
  var bareFunction = require('bare-function');

  return {
    doSomething: function(bareFunctionShadow) {
      var fn, v;
      fn = bareFunctionShadow || bareFunction;
      v = fn();
      return v.toUpperCase();
    }
  };
}
```

**foo-unit-test.js**

```
define(function(require) {
  var bareFunction = require('bare-function');
  var target = require('foo');

  describe('foo', function(){

    describe('doSomething', function(){

      it('should uppercase the result of the bare-function', function() {
        //arrange
        var bareFunctionResult = 'test value';
        var bareFunctionMock = function() { return bareFunctionResult; };

        //act
        var result = target.doSomething(bareFunctionMock);

        //assert
        expect(result).toBe(bareFunctionResult.toUpperCase());  
      });

    });

  });

});
```